# convert database into json with specific format in python

Tags: python, json

I'm beginner in python. I'm trying to read my database and write into json file with following format

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["hello"],
     "responses": ["hello"]
    },
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["are you fine"],
     "responses": ["yeah"]
    }
   ]
}
```

I've following database

```
tag         patterns        responses
greeting    hello           hello
greeting    are you fine    yeah
```

I've tried this code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = connection.cursor()


def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)

result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM reply").fetchall()

data = {}
data['intents'] = [{***some code here***}]

writeToJSONFile('./','intents',data)
```

I'm unable to write code for json part. Any help, suggestion are welcome

Comment: It looks like (from you db) that the patterns and responses is a single value, like a single text entry. Is that correct?

Comment: @Splatmistro in this case key have single value

Comment: In that case, does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that result looks like:

```
>>>print(result)
[['greeting','hello','hello'],['greeting','are you fine','yeah']]
```

The following line will make the data in a dict, the way you want it:

```
data = { 'intents': [ 
              {'tag':row[0],
               'patterns':[row[1]],
               'responses':[row[2]]
              }
              for row in result]
       }
```

**Note**: I tried to make it read easier with formatting, here is the oneline

```
data = { 'intents': [ {'tag':row[0], 'patterns':[row[1]], 'responses':[row[2]]} for row in result]  }
```

You can pretty print the data to help validate that it is correct :

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
{
"intents": [
    {
        "patterns": [
            "hello"
        ],
        "responses": [
            "hello"
        ],
        "tag": "greeting"
    },
    {
        "patterns": [
            "are you fine"
        ],
        "responses": [
            "yeah"
        ],
        "tag": "greeting"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works completely fine for me.  Thank you for your effort

Comment: I'm happy that my problem become challenge for you. I don't get why people down vote my question at first.

Comment: My only guess would be that it looks like you didn't include things you've tried in the `***code here***` bit but they should really downvote and comment why so that you can fix whatever disappointed them.